# User defined Exception doubt

Tags: python

I have this exception class

```
class Value(Exception):
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val = val

    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.val)

raise Value('4')
```

and the exception comes as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<module1>", line 20, in <module>
Value: '4'
```

------------------------------------update------

I found out a typo mistake thanks to mark.... but my problem now is that say I want to display 4 and a string hello along with the error how to do so......

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant to write `val` instead of `value` here:

```
def __str__(self):
    return repr(self.val) # <--- not self.value
```

To display multiple values I'd recommend [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) (requires Python 2.6 or newer). Example:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "Hello: {0}".format(self.val)
```

Another example:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "val1 = {}, val2 = {}".format(self.val1, self.val2)
```

Comment: `val1 = {0.val1}, val2 = {0.val2}.format(self)` works as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> class Value(Exception):
 def __init__(self, val):
  self.val = val
 def __repr__(self):
  return ' ,'.join(str(x) for x in self.val) + ' hello world!'
 def __str__(self):
  return repr(self)
```

of course you can do whatever you want in **init**.. as using the syntax *val (instead of val in init) to use the class Value as you showed in your example and then simply call

Value(4, 2) or Value(4) etc...

edit:

just return self.msg in repr...

```
def __repr__(self):
    return self.val + self.msg #or whatever you want
```

my previous example showed how to accept and print multiple values...if you want just a value and a msg, and display them, you can do this:

```
class Value(Exception):
    def __init__(self, val, msg):
        self.val = val
        self.msg = msg
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Error code: %s  Error message: %s' % (self.val, self.msg)
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

> my problem now is that say I want to display 4 and a string hello along with the error how to do so......

You should put your code inside a try/except code to handle an Exception. Here is an example:

`try:
    if something:
       raise Value('4')
    # do something else here
except Value as valueException:
    print "Hello, it raises an Value exception '%s'" % valueException.message`